# How to correctly write an append query in SQL VBA access

Tags: sql, insert, append

Trying to write VBA to append data tracking info to a table.  But can't seem to get this code to work.

> DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblCabinetPNr14Updates SELECT * FROM
> tblCabinetPNr14, " & "CurrentBOM" & " FROM qryCurrentBOM AS BOMVersion
> " & "WHERE ID=" & ID

Can someone help?

Comment: Is there an error? If so, add it to the question. Could be that there are other columns needed by the INSERT that don't have defaults, and can cause trouble.

Comment: Copy everything from the first double quote to the last, inclusive, and paste in the immediate window after a question mark (?); press enter; review what is printed, you will see the actual SQL (minus the id value after the equal sign. You will see a lot of missing spaces. Also you have two FROM clauses. Write a working SQL as an MsAccess query before you attempt turning it into VBA code.

Comment: what do you mean by "paste in the immediate window"?  I created an MsAccess append query that yielded the correct results and then reviewed it in SQL view.  Then I tried entering this into the VBA code but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Figured it out!  correct SQL:  "INSERT INTO tblCabinetPNr14Updates SELECT *, qryCurrentBOM.CurrentBOM AS BOMVersion FROM tblCabinetPNr14,qryCurrentBOM  " & "WHERE ID=" & ID

Comment: `Can someone help?` is not a programming question ... please ask about the problem, not about someone's availability to assist